# T-SQL - Better alternative to Union All for Analysis of sub-groups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with student information and school grades.  I am then trying to query a resultset showing Key Performance Indicators against the varying student sub-groups we have in school. A very crude example of the end result would be:

**Example table I am trying to create**
Take note that the groups of students have overlap.
The same student can be included in `Whole Year`, `Females` and `Non FSM` etc:

[image]

Now I have achieved this.  I have used aggregate functions and GROUP BY clause for each sub-group, and then combined these queries using UNION ALL to create the table.  A crude example of my code would be:

```
SELECT 'Whole Year' AS [Group], COUNT(student.name) AS [Total No. of Students]

UNION ALL

SELECT student.gender AS [Group], COUNT(student.name) AS [Total No. of Students]
GROUP BY student.gender

UNION ALL

SELECT student.fsm AS [Group], COUNT(student.name) AS [Total No. of Students]
GROUP BY student.fsm
```

The problem is, I need to do this for many Key Performance Indicators, and many sub-groups.  With my current solution, my code is HUGE, and also not very manageable.

I am guessing there is probably a much more elegant solution, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all of your code, but if you do a bit of reading around summarising data with 'rollup' it might be what you're looking for:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: is the Columns are dynamic, based on the number of entries in the 'school grades' ? (ie %withC+,B+,A+ ...ect)?

Comment: MightRearranger thanks for the link.  After reading the article I played around with the CUBE operator, and it possibly would have achieved what I wanted if strickt01 hadn't answered.

Comment: The problem with `CUBE` is that if you are `GROUP`ing by lots of columns you end up with a massive `HAVING` clause in order to filter out all the rows you don't want. In this example I suspect it would end up being more unmanageable than your original implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create your groupings as rows. Currently they are column-based (they are based on column values in `student`). Therefore use the `UNPIVOT` operator to turn the columns into rows against which each grouping holds all student IDs that belong to it.

By putting this mapping into a CTE (essentially a temporary table) you can then join from this to `student` and calculate your KPIs for each grouping:

```
;
with group_cte (student_group_name, student_id)
AS
(
    select student_group, student_id
    from 
    (select e.student_id as total, 
        case when gender = 'male' then e.student_id end as males, 
        case when gender = 'females' then e.student_id end as females,
        -- your other groupings
    from student e) p
    UNPIVOT
    (student_id for student_group 
        in (total, males, females)) unpvt
)
select student_group_name, count(student_id), -- your KPIs...
from group_cte c
inner join student s
on e.student_id = c.student_id
group by student_group_name
```

This should result in much fewer table scans and cleaner SQL.

Comment: This has solved my problem perfectly, thank you.  I have re-produced this query in my environment and it does exactly what I need.  I must admit, this is the first time I have used either CTE or unpivot, and I do not fully understand what is happening in the query (yet).  This is much appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: No problem. An enjoyable challenge! I have amended the answer to try to clarify the workings of the query. However there is never any substitute for running each constituent `SELECT` so as to get an idea of how it is built up.